# Increase the height of JSignature input area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using JSignature to accept the signature. How can i increase the default height? I tried giving height to the signature div but not working as expected.

```
Code:
<div id="signature" style="background-color:#fff9cb;border:0px;height:200px"></div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/willowsystems/jSignature to capture the signature. The Html code is mentioned above to add the Jsignature canvas element. It takes the height dynamically based on screen width and height. I would like to increase the height to 200px.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

replace this line in jSignature Sample

```
var $sigdiv = $("#signature").jSignature({ 'UndoButton': true })
```

to

```
var $sigdiv = $("#signature").jSignature({ 'UndoButton': true, 'width': 400, 'height': 400 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble altering the size or the line width of the signature box in `<div>` (capture) and `<img>` (display) tags.  Try modifying the size with jQuery (and make sure you have jSignature.js added to your project):

```
<div id="mySignatureBox" style="background:#000000; color:#ffffff"></div>   

$('#mySignatureBox').jSignature({ lineWidth: 1, width: 700, height: 200 });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can also use percentage values, this did the job for me:

```
$('#signature').jSignature({
  width: '100%',
  height: 250
});
```

Comment: This translates into width="100"